# What is the range of dimensions for a camera to fit comfortably in a pocket?

Tags: digital, portable

With compact system cameras (bridge cameras, hybrids, etc) the sizes are confusing on whether they are meant to fit into a pocket or not. This depends on the lens as well. When searching for one online and not having a demo camera the dimensions are the best information without a thorough review being avail.

What are the maximum length, width and height measurements for a camera which will fit into a pocket? (excluding the attached lens, as this can be accounted for later)

Comment: How big is a pocket?

Comment: @mattdm Maybe this will help http://www.flickr.com/groups/jeanpocketproject/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a **subjective topic** that many camera reviews mention. A typical females pockets are much, much smaller than any "pocket" camera I've ever owned would fit into. But the pockets of the teenager walking with his pants down to his ankles, big enough for a small DSLR!

The answer to **what is a pocket size camera is up to you**! Personally, I have never put a point and shoot camera directly into my pocket, because I prefer to use a case, that adds too much bulk. I also do not wear pants with pockets large enough to carry anything inside of a case. My cell phone inside a very thin case is about as large as I will go. But, about half of the year here in Minnesota I will wear some type of jacket, so a point and shoot camera inside a case can then be carried in my jacket pocket. The size of the camera case adds much more bulk for me than the .25 - .5 inches that the point and shoot cameras vary in size.

To give you some **rough estimates of what I personally am comfortable with** for a "pocketable" camera:

- 4.7 x 2.9 x 2.5 in (120 x 74 x 63 mm) I used to carry a camera around this size in my BACK jeans pocket. It was HUGE! But in a pinch I could stow it in my back pocket if I had to.
- 4.2 x 2.8 x 1.7 in (106.4 x 71.9 x 42.5 mm) This is probably the maximum I would currently consider "pocket" size. It roughly follows the Canon G series cameras currently. It is not comfortable for me to put into a front jeans pocket, but it is possible.
- **3.9 x 2.4 x 1.1 in** (98.9 x 59.9 x 26.7 mm) This is about the largest I will comfortably stow in my front jeans pocket. This roughly follows the Canon S95 series of cameras size.

Answer (score 4):

Get some cardboard. Build a box. Put it in *your* pocket, the one you intend to carry the camera in. Play with the size of the box until you are comfortable. Use a cardboard tube for the lens.

That is how big your camera can be for *your* pocket.